# World is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a pixel array from an image and i store it into map[].
Then it will test what the color in hex code is and then return the specified number for sprite.
So 0 for grass and 1 for sidewalk right now.

The first part works fine but when I get into draw() the world[] var returns undefined, but in createWorld in the for statements it returns 0 or 1.

This is what I have:

```
function createWorld() {
    for (var y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
            if (map[pl] == '#8aff00') {
                world[x] = [];
                world[x][y] = 0;
                /*alert(x + ', ' + y + ', ' +'green' + ', '
                  + map[pl] + ', ' + world[x] + ',' + world[x][y]);*/
            }
            if (map[pl] == '#000000') {
                world[x] = [];
                world[x][y] = 1;
                /*alert(x + ', ' + y + ', ' +'black' + ', ' 
                 + map[pl] + ', ' + world[x][y]);*/
            }

            pl += 4;
        }
    }
    draw();
}

function draw() {

    if (!spritesheetLoaded) return;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
            switch (world[x][y]) {
                case 1:
                    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
                    sidewalk.srcX * tileWidth, sidewalk.srcY * tileHeight,
                    tileWidth, tileHeight, x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight,
                    tileWidth, tileHeight);
                    break;
                default:
                    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
                    grass.srcX * tileWidth, grass.srcY * tileHeight,
                    tileWidth, tileHeight, x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight,
                    tileWidth, tileHeight);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The spacing got kind of messed up when I posted it sorry.

Comment: Where have you placed `var world = [];`?

Comment: Is `world` undefined or is `world[x][y]` undefined?  The latter will certainly be undefined in many cases.

Comment: `world` does appear to be undefined.

Comment: It's in the top of the code, I didn't put it here, its

Comment: Then what should I call in draw? Why is it undefined? And btw var world is set at the top of my code not in this, but I set as:

Comment: Var world = [[]]; @JamesMontagne

Comment: Haha whooped wrong person @JasonSperske

Comment: if (!world[x])  world[x] =[]; would seem a better start.